# MacOS RPC Interface not working

Tags: rpc, macos

So, I'm just starting and I run a MacOS device. First issue:

"Failed to connect to localhost port 8888: Connection refused" after running `curl http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/get_info` in MacOS

I successfully started running the node I thought, because a chain of transactions were showing, however there is this connection failure on the port.

What is going on?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have the same problem when I attempt this in the Gitpod IDE instead of my local environment...

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether you run nodeos with option `plugin = eosio::chain_api_plugin`. You can add that option when you execute nodeos in command line like `$ nodeos --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin ...` or put it into config.ini of nodeos.

Second, if your nodeos is executed remotely, set option `http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888`. This also can be added to command line command or config.ini.